# Index out of range

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I have the following code in VB.NET:

```
Public Sub New()
    config = ""

    Dim args() As String = System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()
    If args.Count > 1 Then
        config = args(1)
    End If
End Sub
```

I always get the error when it hits the config = args(1) saying the Index is out of bound.

I have no idea how to fix this, or why this is even a problem when I already did the count check! I have debugged and it does grab the command line arguments so that is not a problem.

Comment: That’s almost impossible, unless you have loaded some weird extensions and `Count` here doesn’t refer to `System.Linq.Enumerable.Count`.

Comment: I’m going out on a limb here and guess that you haven’t posted the actual code. Please do so.

Comment: That is the actual code, the thing is that after I Publish the code (to get an .exe) it always breaks on the .exe - I do not get the error when debugging.

Answer (score 0):

You get the length of an array using the `Length` property:

```
If args.Length > 1 Then
```

Anyhow, I tested your code and it works using `Count` too. I don't get the exception that you mention.

Comment: True, but `args.Count()` should return the same.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Yes, I tested it, and as expected it does. I added my findings to the answer.